# Finding minima and replacing values in pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, r, pandas, dataframe

So,I have a data frame where I want to compare the values of one column with an integer to check the minima and replace it in the data frame.
In R I did something like this:
maxPriceRatio = 2.0;
pmin(maxPriceRatio, (rdata[defined, "ABCD"])
It works

I want to do the same thing in Python.
filteredDf.loc[:,'"ABCD'] =  ?
filteredDf["ABCD"] say, has 100 rows. I want to compare each entry with 2.0 and pick the minimum out for the two for the new data frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `np.minimum`

```
filteredDf.loc[:,"ABCD"] = np.minimum(filteredDf.loc[:,"ABCD"], 2.0)
```